# Coremltools converting caffemodel issue

Tags: python, macos, neural-network, coreml, coremltools

There is a Wonderfull setup instruction for [Neural Style](https://github.com/jcjohnson/neural-style) that allows to apply style of any image to my photos.

But it returns .caffemodel format that I want to convert to Core ML format

There is a [Dropbox Link to all the Caffe models](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qvgns8s69k2ze9x/AAB-jTfvecdXYybh93kAlqTAa?dl=0)

I create a python file with:

```
import coremltools

    # Convert a Caffe model to a classifier in Core ML
    coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(
        ('nin_imagenet_conv.caffemodel', 'train_val.prototxt'), predicted_feature_name='class_labels.txt'
    )

    # Now save the model
    coreml_model.save('nin_imagenet_conv.mlmodel')
```

Then in Terminal I run `python convert.py`

But then I get a error:

```
================= Starting Conversion from Caffe to CoreML ======================
Layer 0: Type: 'Data', Name: 'data'. Output(s): 'data', 'label'.
WARNING: Skipping Data Layer 'data' of type 'Data'. It is recommended to use Input layer for deployment.
Layer 1: Type: 'Data', Name: 'data'. Output(s): 'data', 'label'.
WARNING: Skipping Data Layer 'data' of type 'Data'. It is recommended to use Input layer for deployment.
Layer 2: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'conv1'. Input(s): 'data'. Output(s): 'conv1'.
Layer 3: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu0'. Input(s): 'conv1'. Output(s): 'conv1'.
Layer 4: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp1'. Input(s): 'conv1'. Output(s): 'cccp1'.
Layer 5: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu1'. Input(s): 'cccp1'. Output(s): 'cccp1'.
Layer 6: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp2'. Input(s): 'cccp1'. Output(s): 'cccp2'.
Layer 7: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu2'. Input(s): 'cccp2'. Output(s): 'cccp2'.
Layer 8: Type: 'Pooling', Name: 'pool0'. Input(s): 'cccp2'. Output(s): 'pool0'.
Layer 9: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'conv2'. Input(s): 'pool0'. Output(s): 'conv2'.
Layer 10: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu3'. Input(s): 'conv2'. Output(s): 'conv2'.
Layer 11: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp3'. Input(s): 'conv2'. Output(s): 'cccp3'.
Layer 12: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu5'. Input(s): 'cccp3'. Output(s): 'cccp3'.
Layer 13: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp4'. Input(s): 'cccp3'. Output(s): 'cccp4'.
Layer 14: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu6'. Input(s): 'cccp4'. Output(s): 'cccp4'.
Layer 15: Type: 'Pooling', Name: 'pool2'. Input(s): 'cccp4'. Output(s): 'pool2'.
Layer 16: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'conv3'. Input(s): 'pool2'. Output(s): 'conv3'.
Layer 17: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu7'. Input(s): 'conv3'. Output(s): 'conv3'.
Layer 18: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp5'. Input(s): 'conv3'. Output(s): 'cccp5'.
Layer 19: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu8'. Input(s): 'cccp5'. Output(s): 'cccp5'.
Layer 20: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp6'. Input(s): 'cccp5'. Output(s): 'cccp6'.
Layer 21: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu9'. Input(s): 'cccp6'. Output(s): 'cccp6'.
Layer 22: Type: 'Pooling', Name: 'pool3'. Input(s): 'cccp6'. Output(s): 'pool3'.
Layer 23: Type: 'Dropout', Name: 'drop'. Input(s): 'pool3'. Output(s): 'pool3'.
WARNING: Skipping training related layer 'drop' of type 'Dropout'.
Layer 24: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'conv4-1024'. Input(s): 'pool3'. Output(s): 'conv4'.
Layer 25: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu10'. Input(s): 'conv4'. Output(s): 'conv4'.
Layer 26: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp7-1024'. Input(s): 'conv4'. Output(s): 'cccp7'.
Layer 27: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu11'. Input(s): 'cccp7'. Output(s): 'cccp7'.
Layer 28: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'cccp8-1024'. Input(s): 'cccp7'. Output(s): 'cccp8'.
Layer 29: Type: 'ReLU', Name: 'relu12'. Input(s): 'cccp8'. Output(s): 'cccp8'.
Layer 30: Type: 'Pooling', Name: 'pool4'. Input(s): 'cccp8'. Output(s): 'pool4'.
Layer 31: Type: 'Accuracy', Name: 'accuracy'. Input(s): 'pool4', 'label'. Output(s): 'accuracy'.
WARNING: Skipping training related layer 'accuracy' of type 'Accuracy'.
Layer 32: Type: 'SoftmaxWithLoss', Name: 'loss'. Input(s): 'pool4', 'label'. WARNING: Skipping training related layer 'loss' of type 'SoftmaxWithLoss'.

================= Summary of the conversion: ===================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert.py", line 5, in <module>
    ('nin_imagenet_conv.caffemodel', 'train_val.prototxt'), predicted_feature_name='class_labels.txt'
  File "/Users/pavel.tarasevich/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 192, in convert
    predicted_feature_name)
  File "/Users/pavel.tarasevich/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 260, in _export
    predicted_feature_name)
RuntimeError: Unable to infer input name and dimensions. Please provide a .prototxt file with 'Input' layer and dimensions defined.
```

Comment: The error message says what's wrong: you need to change the prototxt file to give it an Input layer with an image width and height. It also looks like you're using the training prototxt rather than the deployment one.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans I provided the dropbox link with another prototxt file, but for me it doesn't work too. On the other case I don't know to add in input layer with image width and height Pls could you help with that on the example. I can start a bounty if it helps

Comment: I added how to do this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the prototxt file, add the following:

```
input: "data"
input_dim: 1
input_dim: 3
input_dim: 224
input_dim: 224
```

The order of the dimensions is: batch size, channel, height, width. You need to add one of these sections for every input in the model.

The name of the input (here, `"data"`) must be the same as the `bottom` field in the first layer.